# .format is not a function at eval

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting

i have the following function that i am trying to create that groups dates together so that i can get a total amount of cost for the group days as follows

```
function CreateDailyBalanceTable(result) {

  var groupdates = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    if (groupdates.indexOf(result[i].ResultDateTime.format("dd-MM-yyyy")) < 0) { //it keeps on throwing an error at this line
      groupdates.push(result[i].ResultDateTime.format("dd-MM-yyyy"));
    }
  }
}
```

this is an example of the `result[i].ResultDateTime` how it looks

```
"2015-08-13T11:41:51.147"
```

but when it reaches this line "`if (groupdates.indexOf(result[i].ResultDateTime.format("dd-MM-yyyy")) < 0)"` it breaks and says ***"result[i].ResultDateTime.format is not a function
    at eval (eval at CreateDailyBalanceTable)"***

how do i fix this?

Comment: "2015-08-13T11:41:51.147" is a String when `.format` is a method of Date object

Comment: Actually I'm not sure about the last part, I can't find *Date.prototype.format* on MDN

Comment: `toLocaleFormat`

Comment: @DaveNewton still returns the same error

Comment: Still not a date.

Comment: @CedricCholley—there is no *format* method of ECMAScript Date objects.

Comment: Looks similar to `DateInstance.toISOString()` format.

Comment: @DaveNewton— [*toLocaleFormat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleFormat) is non–standard and not on track to become one. Perhaps you mean [*toLocaleString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString).

Comment: @RobG Oops--yep.

Comment: @RobG the toLocaleString brings back the entire string and not just the date

Comment: @josh—[*options parameters*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) can be used to format the string. See [*How to format a JavaScript date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date?r=SearchResults&s=1|1457.0205).